# what happens when i refresh a jquery mobile page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, dom

**What happens when a JQUERY MOBILE page is refreshed?**
I use ajax to fetch data in a variable called "json" on *page1*, when user clicks a particular dynamically generated element, i store the id of clicked element in a session variable and `changePage()` to a new JQM *page2* where i use `json.thepropertyiwant` to generate a list, everything works fine, even back and forward buttons work perfectly however if i refresh *page2*
then  `json.thepropertyiwant` becomes undefined here is the error i get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'responseData' of undefined
```

*i am using a multipage in a single html5 page model*

**edit:**

- I have used variable name `json` and not `JSON` i just typed it like
  that to emphasize, however now i think that was foolish!
- I have also figured my problem. My mistake was that i was assuming
  page refresh would call `pageinit` for the page i am on but it works
  no differently than a normal html page refresh and triggers
  `document.ready` each time and then `pageinit` for the page i am on.

  **Is there a way to listen to a
  `pagerefresh` event and override its normal functionality?**

Comment: give some code that you used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you generate the dynamic content of page2 in some event. 
I believe that the event is pageinit or pagecreate. Those events fire only once (if you have ajax page load set to true). 
What happens is that you request the data when you load page1 (something like pageinit?)
When you refresh page2, the data is not there because the event that you request your data in, is not firing, which is completely normal, because when you refresh page2, page1 has nothing to do with it. Post the section of your code where you request your data, and the section where you generate the dynamic content for page2 for more.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out i have this realization in the edits thanks any way!

Comment: I am curious, is there a way to override the pagerefresh event functionality?

Comment: You want to prevent refreshing I suppose?

Comment: No, just want to listen to the "refresh" and then bind a custom function to it which will decide what happens now, but i guess the browser won't let me do that! I can bind the F5 key-press but not the browser refresh button i suppose...

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... there's a few issues going on here.

- For starters, don't use a variable called 'JSON'.  That's no good - there's already a global object called JSON which is used for parsing and encoding JSON!  You could accidentally overwrite it.
- As you discovered, if you store data in a variable in javascript - that variable is only in memory for the current page. If you refresh the page, then that variable will no longer be in memory.

  But that's not really anything to do with jQuery Mobile. That's just how web browsers work - javascript structures created in-memory are not persisted between page refreshes.

  Generally you need to save the data yourself using localStorage or cookies for it to persist between page refreshes.
- Typically you don't refresh a jQuery Mobile app anyway. So the previous point is generally not too much of an issue.  A user refreshing the page is like rebooting the app.

  The app should when it starts reload any data that it needs, i.e.
  from localStorage, from cookies, or make some new ajax calls to
  reload. You would have to program that logic in.